# How do I change who receives contact form emails?

Tags: magento2.2.4

I have been trying to change the recipient of our contact form emails, but so far no luck. I have tried to change all 5 emails under `System > Store Email` Addresses and also the one under `System > Contacts`. No luck. Store view is set to Default Config.

I have tried to look in form.phtml, but I it looks pretty generic:

```
$j('#contactForm').submit(function(){
        if($j('#name').val().length < 3) {
            $j('#name, label[for="name"]').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $j('#name, label[for="name"]').removeClass('error');
        }

        if(!pattern.test($j('#email').val())) {
            $j('#email, label[for="email"]').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $j('#email, label[for="email"]').removeClass('error');
        }

        if($j('#comment').val().length < 3) {
            $j('#comment, label[for="comment"]').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $j('#comment, label[for="comment"]').removeClass('error');
        }

        if($j('#contactForm label').hasClass('error')) {
            $j('#warning').show();
            return false;
        } else {
            $j('#warning').hide();
        var formAction = $j('#contactForm').attr('action');

        var $jformItself = $j('#contactForm :input');

        var values = {};

        $jformItself.each(function() {
            values[this.name] = $j(this).val();
        });

        $j.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "/js/postmail.php",

            data: values, // serializes the form's elements.

            success: function(data)
```

Comment: _Store view is set to Default Config._ Have you checked the other views?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Recipient email address from the below configuration.

```
Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> (General) Contacts -> Email Options
```

[image]

Uncheck the `Use System Value` and the enter the receiver email id and press save config.

If you want to change the email id for different store.You need to choose  the Store View config

[image]

and change email id like above.

Comment: I believe I have already done that: https://i.imgur.com/TU6SZKa.jpg

I have changed it for both local language and default just in case. Yet the mails still goes to the original receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Recipient email address from here.
First Logged-in admin site.

> Store->Configuration->General->Contacts

Here we have "Send Emails To" configuration where we can enter your Recipient email address. For that we have to unchecked "Use system value" checkbox to enable the Parameter. Please see attached screenshot for better understanding. Hope this will help you.

[image]